# WEBdav map network drive

Tags: windows, ubuntu-14.04, webdav

I need to connect to my ubuntu Box 1404 server, however I have installed apache2 and enabled webdav

Here is my apache2 conf:

```
DavLockDB /var/www/DavLock <VirtualHost *:80>
           ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
           DocumentRoot /var/www/html
           ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
           CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
           Alias /webdav/test1 /var/www/webdav/test1
           <Directory /var/www/webdav/test1>
                   DAV On
                   AuthType Digest
                   AuthName "webdav"
                   AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/users.password
                   Require user test1
           </Directory> </VirtualHost>
```

The issue is If I map the network drive it show
"The folder you enter does not appear to be invalid...."

I try to use Command prompt as Administrator:
net use W: "http://testserver/webdav/test1" /user:test1 myownpass
I got error 67

However If I go to my site using chrome or any web browser, I can see the site http://testserver/webdav/test1/index.html

Any help please will be great!

Note: I almost hit my head on the wall :D

Comment: `net use` is not designed to map to website URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I have work on it, and it seems working now, however the windows explorer cannot remmeber credential everytime I restart my machine.

Tried : http://www.geeks-on-wheels.net/solved-unable-to-save-remember-password-for-mapped-webdav-folder/

and it is still required to login again